# save checkbox status after page reload

Tags: input, checkbox

help to make the checkbox status persist after reloading the page, thanks!

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<input type="checkbox" name="enable" id="enable" />Enable
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" disabled />


<script>

window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById('enable').onchange=function(){
        var txt = document.getElementById('name');
        txt.disabled = !this.checked;
    };
};

</script>
```

Comment: Could you give more contexte, why this current code doesn't work, error etc..?

Comment: after reloading the page, the check disappears, I would like it to remain, thanks!

Comment: my choice was saved in cookies